# Add sound to swf file via SwfDotNet tool

Tags: c#, flash

I need to make swf file (slide show) from images and sounds (narrations). 
I am trying to use SwfDotNet tool for it.

There is article which describes how to add images to swf http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/jpeg2swf.aspx?fid=369197&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=21#xx0xx

I can't add sound to swf.
I try to use next code, but it doesn't work.
Looks that DefineSoundTag works because file size is increased, but StartSoundTag doesn't work.

```
var soundId = swf.GetNewDefineId();
swf.Tags.Add(DefineSoundTag.FromFile(soundId, fileName));

var soundInfo = new SoundInfo() {
    InPoint = 1,
    OutPoint = 10000
};

swf.Tags.Add(new StartSoundTag(soundId, soundInfo));
```

Does anyone know how to add sound to swf via swfdotnet tool?

Comment: have you  got any solution to this?if yes please shere i also trying to do same

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find solution. It was just research, so I didn't spend too much time on this problem.